# Calculating a total cost in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a trip planner in python, but after I defined all the functions I'm not able to call and calculate them in the last function `tripCost()`.

In `tripCost`, I want to put the days and travel destination (`city`) and the program runs the functions and gives me the exact result of all the 3 functions previously defined.

**Code:**

```
def hotelCost(): 
    days = raw_input ("How many nights will you stay at the hotel?")
    total = 140 * int(days) print "The total cost is",total,"dollars"


def planeRideCost(): 
    city = raw_input ("Wich city will you travel to\n")
    if city == 'Charlotte':
        return "The cost is 183$"
    elif city == 'Tampa':
        return "The cost is 220$"
    elif city == 'Pittsburgh':
        return "The cost is 222$"
    elif city == 'Los Angeles':
        return "The cost is 475$"
    else:
        return "That's not a valid destination"

def rentalCarCost(): 
    rental_days = raw_input ("How many days will you rent the car\n")   
    discount_3 = 40 * int(rental_days) * 0.2 
    discount_7 = 40 * int(rental_days) * 0.5 
    total_rent3 = 40 * int(rental_days) - discount_3
    total_rent7 = 40 * int(rental_days) - discount_7
    cost_day = 40 * int(rental_days) 

    if int(rental_days) >= 3: 
        print "The total cost is", total_rent3, "dollars"
    elif int(rental_days) >= 7: 
        print "The total cost is", total_rent7, "dollars"
    else: 
        print "The total cost is", cost_day, "dollars"

def tripCost():
    travel_city = raw_input ("What's our destination\n")
    days_travel = raw_input ("\nHow many days will you stay\n")
    total_trip_cost = hotelCost(int(day_travel)) + planeRideCost (str(travel_city)) + rentalCost (int(days_travel))
    return "The total cost with the trip is", total_trip_cost

tripCost()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your  `def rentalCarCost():` is returning nothing..
2. `rentalCost (int(days_travel))` I can't see such function.

Update:

```
def hotelCost(): 
    days = raw_input ("How many nights will you stay at the hotel?")
    total = 140 * int(days) print "The total cost is",total,"dollars"
    return total


def planeRideCost(): 
    city = raw_input ("Wich city will you travel to\n")
    if city == 'Charlotte':
        return 183
    elif city == 'Tampa':
        return 220
    elif city == 'Pittsburgh':
        return 222
    elif city == 'Los Angeles':
        return 475
    else:
        print "That's not a valid destination"

def rentalCarCost(): 
    rental_days = raw_input ("How many days will you rent the car\n")   
    discount_3 = 40 * int(rental_days) * 0.2 
    discount_7 = 40 * int(rental_days) * 0.5 
    total_rent3 = 40 * int(rental_days) - discount_3
    total_rent7 = 40 * int(rental_days) - discount_7
    cost_day = 40 * int(rental_days) 

    if int(rental_days) >= 3: 
        print "The total cost is", total_rent3, "dollars"
        return total_rent3
    elif int(rental_days) >= 7: 
        print "The total cost is", total_rent7, "dollars"
        return total_rent7
    else: 
        print "The total cost is", cost_day, "dollars"
        return cost_day

def tripCost():
    travel_city = raw_input ("What's our destination\n")
    days_travel = raw_input ("\nHow many days will you stay\n")
    total_trip_cost = hotelCost(int(day_travel)) + planeRideCost () + rentalCarCost(int(days_travel))
    return "The total cost with the trip is", total_trip_cost

tripCost()
```

Comment: The rentalCost is in the bottom, on the total_trip_cost variable, it's the last one.

Comment: Sorry, total_trip_cost = hotelCost(int(day_travel)) + planeRideCost (str(travel_city)) + rentalCost (int(days_travel)) should be total_trip_cost = hotelCost(int(day_travel)) + planeRideCost (str(travel_city)) + rentalCarCost (int(days_travel))

Comment: Where? In your code and mine the total_trip_cost = hotelCost(int(days_travel)) + planeRideCost (str(travel_city)) + rentalCarCost (int(days_travel)) was missing an s in the days_travel, appart from that I can't run it

Comment: You have messed up whole code:- `planeRideCost (str(travel_city))` has no argument..

Comment: total_trip_cost = hotelCost(int(days_travel)) + planeRideCost (str(travel_city)) + rentalCost (int(days_travel)) I pasted wrong

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you separate user interaction from calculations. I made some changes, and I am pasting it as an example, I am not saying this code does the right thing for your problem, it is just to illustrate that separation. You can also use a cost_table as a dictionary:

```
cost_table = {
    'Charlotte':183,
    'Tampa':220,
    'Pittsburgh':222,
    'Los Angeles':475
    }

def hotel_cost(nights): 
    cost = 140 * int(nights)
    return cost

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    return cost_table[city]

def rental_car_cost(days): 
    discount_3 = 40 * days * 0.2 
    discount_7 = 40 * days * 0.5 
    total_rent3 = 40 * days - discount_3
    total_rent7 = 40 * days - discount_7
    cost_day = 40 * days 

    if days >= 3:
        return total_rent3
    elif days >= 7:
        return total_rent7
    else: 
        return cost_day

def trip_cost(city, nights, car_days):
    total = hotel_cost(nights) + plane_ride_cost(city) +\
            rental_car_cost(car_days)
    return total

city = None
while True:
    city = raw_input ("What's our destination?\n")
    if city not in cost_table:
        print "That's not a valid destination."
    else:
        break

hotel_nights = raw_input ("\nHow many nights will you stay?\n")
car_days = raw_input ("How many days will you rent the car?\n")   

total_trip_cost = hotel_cost(int(hotel_nights)) +\
                  plane_ride_cost(city) +\
                  rental_car_cost(int(car_days))

print "The total cost with the trip is", total_trip_cost, "dollars."
```